# Multilevel header in jqgrid with same column names

Tags: jqgrid

I am converting datatables to jqgrid.Here is what my datatable sample looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XSev.png)

The problem I am facing is due to same column names inside each header.How can we use 'setGroupHeaders' in jqgrid to achieve the structure as shown? What should the colModel, colNames and setGroupHeaders look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy to use. [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/MultilevelHeaders.htm) displays the results like

[image]

The corresponding code is below

```js
.jqGrid("setGroupHeaders", {
    useColSpanStyle: true,
    groupHeaders: [
        {
            startColumnName: "amount",
            numberOfColumns: 6,
            titleText: "<span style='font-size:18px'>Order Details</span>"
        }
    ]
})
.jqGrid("setGroupHeaders", {
    useColSpanStyle: true,
    groupHeaders: [
        { startColumnName: "amount", numberOfColumns: 3, titleText: "<em>Price</em>" },
        { startColumnName: "closed", numberOfColumns: 2, titleText: "Shiping" }
    ]
});
```

I remind that I use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) in the demo. It's the fork which I develop after making old fork developed by Tony commercial (see [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)) and renaming it to Guriddo jqGrid JS (see [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)).

Comment: But since my colName = ['id', 'Time', 'Total Sales', 'Total Sales', 'Total Sales' ....], won't the startColumnName be ambigous because of the same name.

Comment: @johndoe: I'm not sure that I understand you correctly. Te values which one have to use in `startColumnName` (see the options of `setGroupHeaders`) come from `name` property of `colModel`. It's not important which *texts* you use in `colName`. The value of `name` property have to be unique and should corresponds the rules of `id` (no spaces for example). Thus you will have no problems.